# Failed to open connection to SMTP Server on OBIEE 12C

Tags: obiee

I had recently installed obiee 12c  with version Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.4.0 on my windows 10.
Everything is working fine as i am able to create dashboards/report.

But related to scheduling agents / sending mails from OBIEE i am getting the following error.

```
    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
[nQSError: 75027] Failed to open connection to SMTP Server (host localhost; port 25).    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
    ...Trying SMTP Delivery loop again... Sleeping for 3 seconds.    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
[nQSError: 75027] Failed to open connection to SMTP Server (host localhost; port 25).    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
    ...Trying SMTP Delivery loop again... Sleeping for 5 seconds.    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
[nQSError: 75027] Failed to open connection to SMTP Server (host localhost; port 25).    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
    ...Trying SMTP Delivery loop again... Sleeping for 8 seconds.    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
[nQSError: 75027] Failed to open connection to SMTP Server (host localhost; port 25).    AgentID: /shared/Agents/GDMR_DM_Summary_report
    Exceeded number of SMTP delivery retries.
```

I crosschecked both EM and schedulerconfig.xml file and the entries are same there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 is a desktop operating system and never was, is not and never will be supported.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/obiee-122140-certmatrix-4472983.xlsx

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed information. It helped a lot.